# How to send binary string as .bin using a chooser intent?

Tags: java, android

I have a byte[ ] that contains a serialized object. I am trying to send the object via a .bin file.

```
Intent shareBinaryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
StringBuilder binaryString = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : binary) {
    binaryString.append(Integer.toBinaryString((int) b));
}
shareBinaryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, binaryString.toString());
shareBinaryIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareBinaryIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.appname_send_binary_button_text)));
```

When I try printing binaryString, I get a string of ones and zeros, but when I try sharing, it says the content is empty.

Thank you!

---

Follow up:

I tried greenapps suggestions, but I'm sharing a malformed binary:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "binary_payload.bin");
        try {
          f.createNewFile();
          FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
          fo.write(mBinaryResponsePayload);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, e, "Exception occurred while writing a binary file");
        }
        shareBinaryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "binary_payload.bin"));
        shareBinaryIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareBinaryIntent,
            getResources().getText(R.string.appname_send_binary_button_text)));
      }
    }
```

Any suggestions? I'm really stuck

Comment: It is a string. Not a stream. `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  binaryString.toString());`. And adapt the type.

Comment: Or you should put `binary` in a ByteArrayOutput/InputStream to use stream.

Comment: Using `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`, is there a way to save the file as a .bin instead of .txt?

Comment: If you save the bytes of `binary` to file hen you can open a stream from that file. But then you use EXTRA_STREAM.

Comment: Added a follow up--thanks!

Comment: The setType should be text i think as it is just text you stream.